# How to check if an element does not exist without getting a cypress error?

Tags: javascript, cypress

I am using Cypress for testing a web application and I want to execute some cypress commands after checking if an element does not exit.

I have tried with this but Cypress will show an error message that the element does not exist and it will stop the test.

```js
    // The user is not logged, so the "logout" button is not displayed
    if (!cy.get("a").contains("Logout")) { // <--Cypress will stop here
        // If "logout" button does not exist, then log in
        cy.get("a").contains("Login").click();
    }
    // continue with the test
    // ...
```

What I want is to check if the element does not exit without getting the error, is there a way to approach this without using loops or long waits?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by using `then` on an element that will *always* exist (the body), and then using `find` to check for your element.  If you find it, you proceed as normal.

```
cy.get('body').then($body => {
   // If the element doesn't exist, exit the callback
   if (!$body.find('a:contains("Login")')).length) return;

    // If it does, click on it
    cy.get('a').contains('Login').click();
});
```

Comment: This only works for static elements (already loaded). It fails if element or it's event depends on something async - there is no retry with this code.

Answer (score 0):

It is very simple. Basically you need to use the Cypress assertion methods i.e should and you can play with it. Below is the working solution and you can use it.

```
cy.get(`.logout-button`).should('not.be.visible').then(condition => {
    if (condition) {
        cy.get("[data-qa='input-username']").type('abcd');
        cy.get("[data-qa='input-password']").type('abcd');
        cy.get('.button').click();
    }
});
```

Let me know if you face any issues.

Comment: This will still crash the application. There is  no catch for an error. If the condition is not met, the program will simply skip it and do nothing which is not what Luis wants.